# Setting self reference in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, self-reference

So, I have a user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :partner, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :id
    belongs_to :inverse_partner, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :id
end
```

And each user has an `id` (prepared by the scaffold), a `partner_id` and a `inverse_partner_id` column in the `users` table.

However, when I try to to do this:

```
aka[x].partner = shiro[x]
```

Where both `aka[x]` and `shiro[x]` are `User`s, I get this weird error where the SQL statement indicates that I'm setting `id` and not `partner_id` as I intended to:

`SQLite3::MismatchException: datatype mismatch: UPDATE "users" SET "id" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "users"."id" = 4`

I'm obviously doing something very wrong. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only required change I see is in your associations' `foreign_key` option.

With the current setup you are basically using one single column for three different purposes i.e. primary key for `users` table, foreign key for `partner` association and foreign key for `inverse_partner` association.  So, when this is done and you try to set partner such errors can be expected.

Set appropriate foreign keys for each relations as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :partner, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :partner_id
    belongs_to :inverse_partner, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :inverse_partner_id
end
```

Comment: Ah, I was under the impression that "foreign key" is the column in the destination table which `partner_id` should store a copy of. That's what happens when you don't know your SQL. Thanks!

It does seem kind of redundant though given that we know it "has_one :name", what would be an actual use where the has_one :name and the foreign key (`name_id`) differ in `name`?

Comment: @peteykun, in such cases yes it could have been implied that the foreign key would be `name_id` for an association name `:name`.  It will probably hold true for most cases but when you want to use a different association name keeping the foreign key `name_id` then this feature becomes very useful.